# How to view Crash Reports from TestFlight Beta tester in Organizer

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode-organizer

I have a beta build of my app that i give to some extern testers via TestFlight. One tester has a problem with the build and I also see that his version crashes in iTunes Connect. 
[image: itunes Connect and organizer]

When I go to iTunes Connect -> Select my App -> and then go to activity and select the build I see that that there are crashes.

Then I open the Organizer from xCode -> Window -> Organizer and select my app and then go to Crashes tab it shows me that I got no crashes.

Th tester activated the option "Share with App-Developers" in Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnose & Usage

What do I do wrong that it shows me no crashes in the organizer?

Thanks for your time and merry Christmas!

Comment: I have same problem. Did you get it solved ?